# How to provide loop for char A to Z which is passed in XPath after that may be we don't need to write XPath for multiple times

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Are there any solutions for XPath?
I want to traverse from char '**A**' to '**Z**', but the problem is which is indide the XPath...

So I think we solve this by loop, but I do not know how to provide s loop for that... For code optimization we do not need to write XPath for multiple times..

I have tried it by loop, but it doesn't work.

```
WebElement A = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='**A**']"));
act.click(A).perform();
char c = 'A';
for (c='A';c<='Z';c++)
{
     String s = Character.toString(c);          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) - define a "template" with the fixed structure of the string, and the format specifier.
Presuming you want to replace the `"A"` in the `"**A**"` text:

```
String templ = "//a[text()='**%s**']";
for (char c='A'; c<='Z'; c++){
     WebElement A = driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(templ, c)));
     /* if you want to see the constructed string/locator:
     System.out.println(String.format(templ, c)); */
     act.click(A).perform();
}
```

Comment: Mr. Todor its not working char is not change in xpath and its click to 'A'  only again and again...

Comment: That is quite strange - it will either work, or not at all, can't use only 'A' because that string is not even defined anywhere. Are you sure you took my code sample in full? See here, the string formatting works as expected - https://repl.it/repls/NormalInsecureDrawings

Comment: Thank you sir,   its working well actually the problem were in my selenium code...

Answer (score 0):

Make the xpath selector dynamic, this is sample logic, you can improve later, try this:

```
String[] letters = {"A","B","C"....};
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

for (int i=0; i<letters.length(); i++)
{
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()=\"**" + letters[i] + "**\"]"));
    action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
}
```